# java license enforcement, algorithm for creating activation key?

Tags: java, security, licensing, copy-protection, license-key

I've decided to use the TrueLicense library to enforce a copy protection for an Java application I developed. Since TrueLicense does not offer a copy protection schema, I need one. I simply want to use the Company Name in combination with the Mac ID to create a license. 
What I need is an algorithm to create an activation key from Company Name and the Mac ID, and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction?

I understand that a knowledgeable person can crack an application within minutes. I understand that no matter what protection I use someone can always get past it. My intention is to unable simple users from copying the application onto multiple machines.

Once again, I need an algorithm to create the activation key from Company Name and Mac ID. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simple scheme, you could put the company name and the MAC address together, compute a hash (e.g. [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)), and use that as the activation key.

For some Java code, see [Compute SHA-1 of byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515489/java-compute-sha-1)

Comment: But how do you get a MAC address from Java?