# Decimal values and hex decimal are not equal in SHA512 output

Tags: java, hex, decimal, sha512

I have tried to implement a program to hash an integer array using SHA-512. I found some [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515489/compute-sha-1-of-byte-array) [solution2](http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-calculate-md5-and-sha-hash-values-in-java) to convert the `byte[]` which contains decimal values to hexadecimals. When I compared the string output to decimal values I found out that for negative values there are some differences. I don't know what is the problem. I tried to convert values to each other and also looked at unsigned, etc but I can not found out what is wrong.
FYI, I want to use bytes in an xor function and don't need strings but I'm scared that some thing might be wrong in my code.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author martin
 */
public class NewMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Integer[][] integerBlock = new Integer[5][5];
        //put some values in the matrix integerBlock
        int i,j;
        for(i=0; i<integerBlock.length; i++){
            for(j=0; j<integerBlock.length; j++){
                integerBlock[i][j] = i+j;
            }
        }
        //convert integerBlock to a string
        String str = IntToStr(integerBlock);
        System.out.println("original string is :      " + str);

        //hash the string using SHA512
        byte[] shaByteResult = SHA512(str);

        //print the generated key in hex
        System.out.println("byteArray2Hex  method:    " + byteArray2Hex(shaByteResult));
        System.out.println("byteArray2Hex2 method:    " + byteArray2Hex2(shaByteResult));

        //print the generated key in decimal
        System.out.print("Decimal values in bytes[]:");
        for(i=0; i< shaByteResult.length ;i++)
                System.out.print(shaByteResult[i]);      

        System.out.println("Compare decimal and correspondig hex");
        for(i=0; i< shaByteResult.length ;i++)
                System.out.println("bytes[" +i +"] = " + " decimal is " + shaByteResult[i] + "  hexadecimal " + Integer.toString((shaByteResult[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
}

    public static String IntToStr(Integer[][] integerBlock){
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();

        int i,j;
        for(i=0; i<integerBlock.length; i++){
            for(j=0; j<integerBlock.length; j++){
                SB.append(integerBlock[i][j].toString());
                //stringBlock = stringBlock.concat(integerBlock[i][j].toString());                
            }
        }
        return SB.toString();
    }

    private static String byteArray2Hex(final byte[] bytes) {

        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();

        for (byte b : bytes) {
            formatter.format("%02x", b);
        }
        return formatter.toString();
    }
    //another solution
    private static String byteArray2Hex2(final byte[] bytes) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i;

        for(i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++)
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] SHA512(String str){
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
            md.update(str.getBytes());
            bytes = md.digest();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
         return bytes;
    }    
}
```

The out put is:

```
original string is :      0123412345234563456745678
byteArray2Hex  method:    0fe5246a2a26080194c19e86ee1e6a40ceb298194190eacace0d3b1499186220b5cd92a1bdd25f8b4023566c211cc462974c3884a128336b76a1e990fe6f3c54
byteArray2Hex2 method:    0fe5246a2a26080194c19e86ee1e6a40ceb298194190eacace0d3b1499186220b5cd92a1bdd25f8b4023566c211cc462974c3884a128336b76a1e990fe6f3c54
Decimal values in bytes[]:15-2736106423881-108-63-98-122-183010664-50-78-1042565-112-22-54-50135920-103249832-75-51-110-95-67-4695-1176435861083328-6098-1057656-124-954051107118-95-23-112-21116084Compare decimal and correspondig hex
bytes[0] =  decimal is 15  hexadecimal 0f
bytes[1] =  decimal is -27  hexadecimal e5
bytes[2] =  decimal is 36  hexadecimal 24
bytes[3] =  decimal is 106  hexadecimal 6a
bytes[4] =  decimal is 42  hexadecimal 2a
bytes[5] =  decimal is 38  hexadecimal 26
bytes[6] =  decimal is 8  hexadecimal 08
bytes[7] =  decimal is 1  hexadecimal 01
bytes[8] =  decimal is -108  hexadecimal 94
bytes[9] =  decimal is -63  hexadecimal c1
bytes[10] =  decimal is -98  hexadecimal 9e
bytes[11] =  decimal is -122  hexadecimal 86
bytes[12] =  decimal is -18  hexadecimal ee
bytes[13] =  decimal is 30  hexadecimal 1e
bytes[14] =  decimal is 106  hexadecimal 6a
bytes[15] =  decimal is 64  hexadecimal 40
bytes[16] =  decimal is -50  hexadecimal ce
bytes[17] =  decimal is -78  hexadecimal b2
bytes[18] =  decimal is -104  hexadecimal 98
bytes[19] =  decimal is 25  hexadecimal 19
bytes[20] =  decimal is 65  hexadecimal 41
bytes[21] =  decimal is -112  hexadecimal 90
bytes[22] =  decimal is -22  hexadecimal ea
bytes[23] =  decimal is -54  hexadecimal ca
bytes[24] =  decimal is -50  hexadecimal ce
bytes[25] =  decimal is 13  hexadecimal 0d
bytes[26] =  decimal is 59  hexadecimal 3b
bytes[27] =  decimal is 20  hexadecimal 14
bytes[28] =  decimal is -103  hexadecimal 99
bytes[29] =  decimal is 24  hexadecimal 18
bytes[30] =  decimal is 98  hexadecimal 62
bytes[31] =  decimal is 32  hexadecimal 20
bytes[32] =  decimal is -75  hexadecimal b5
bytes[33] =  decimal is -51  hexadecimal cd
bytes[34] =  decimal is -110  hexadecimal 92
bytes[35] =  decimal is -95  hexadecimal a1
bytes[36] =  decimal is -67  hexadecimal bd
bytes[37] =  decimal is -46  hexadecimal d2
bytes[38] =  decimal is 95  hexadecimal 5f
bytes[39] =  decimal is -117  hexadecimal 8b
bytes[40] =  decimal is 64  hexadecimal 40
bytes[41] =  decimal is 35  hexadecimal 23
bytes[42] =  decimal is 86  hexadecimal 56
bytes[43] =  decimal is 108  hexadecimal 6c
bytes[44] =  decimal is 33  hexadecimal 21
bytes[45] =  decimal is 28  hexadecimal 1c
bytes[46] =  decimal is -60  hexadecimal c4
bytes[47] =  decimal is 98  hexadecimal 62
bytes[48] =  decimal is -105  hexadecimal 97
bytes[49] =  decimal is 76  hexadecimal 4c
bytes[50] =  decimal is 56  hexadecimal 38
bytes[51] =  decimal is -124  hexadecimal 84
bytes[52] =  decimal is -95  hexadecimal a1
bytes[53] =  decimal is 40  hexadecimal 28
bytes[54] =  decimal is 51  hexadecimal 33
bytes[55] =  decimal is 107  hexadecimal 6b
bytes[56] =  decimal is 118  hexadecimal 76
bytes[57] =  decimal is -95  hexadecimal a1
bytes[58] =  decimal is -23  hexadecimal e9
bytes[59] =  decimal is -112  hexadecimal 90
bytes[60] =  decimal is -2  hexadecimal fe
bytes[61] =  decimal is 111  hexadecimal 6f
bytes[62] =  decimal is 60  hexadecimal 3c
bytes[63] =  decimal is 84  hexadecimal 54
```

Comment: You're aware that Java bytes are signed?

Answer (score 0):

> A constant holding the maximum value a byte can have, 2^7-1

It means each byte has value between -127 and 127 the most significant bit is used as the sign flag. Thus,

```
bytes[0] =  decimal is 15  hexadecimal 0f and binary is  0000 1111
bytes[1] =  decimal is -27  hexadecimal e5 and binary is 1110 0101 is 229 unsigned
bytes[2] =  decimal is 36  hexadecimal 24 and binary is  0010 0100
bytes[3] =  decimal is 106  hexadecimal 6a and binary is 0110 1010
bytes[4] =  decimal is 42  hexadecimal 2a and binary is  0010 1010
bytes[5] =  decimal is 38  hexadecimal 26 and binary is  0010 0110
bytes[6] =  decimal is 8  hexadecimal 08 and binary is   0000 1000 
bytes[7] =  decimal is 1  hexadecimal 01 and binary is   0000 0001
```

Then, Java byte is signed and is interpreted as two compliments that means all bits are reversed and added by one. Thus, for `e5` or `229` or `1110 0101`

`1110 0101` --twoCom- > 0001 1010 --(+1)--> 0001 1011 (27)
apply sign bit --- > -27